# Sublime 3, snippet for python function docstring with arguments and return

Tags: python, code-snippets, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to write a snippet to add docstring to Python function:

for example:

```
def foo(a):

    b=a+1

    return b
```

should produce the following

```
def foo(a):
    """One liner description

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : type
        some comment

    Returns
    -------

    b : type
        some comment

    """

    b=a+1

    return b
```

My first attempt is this snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
"""${1:One liner description}

Parameters
----------
${2}
Returns
-------
${3}
"""
    ]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>docstring</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>Adds a docstring skeleton to function</description>
</snippet>
```

which produces the following when typing docstring and then Tab:

```
def foo(a):
    """One liner description

    Parameters
    ----------

    Returns
    -------

    """

    b=a+1

    return b
```

How can I get the parameters and the return values, such "a" and "b" in the example, automatically detected inside the snippet?

Comment: Just to note you that there exist a defacto standard way to document parameters and return values in Python and it is here:http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#info-field-lists (Though it is not pretty)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `:<`*default value*`>` after the `#` in each `${#}` stop-point:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
"""${1:One liner description}

Parameters
----------
${2:a} : ${3:type}

Returns
-------
${4:b} : ${5:type}
"""
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>docstring</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.python</scope>
    <description>Adds a docstring skeleton to function</description>
</snippet>
```

Comment: This misunderstood my question: the purpose is to have a generic way to detect the arguments and returns of the function and add the corresponding entries in the snippet. a and b here are just to give an example

Comment: AFAIK you can't do all that with a ST snippet. Even if there's another way, detecting types will be difficult, especially for return values since a function can have more than one.

Comment: Python function can't return more that one value. It can only gives the illusion it does by returning an iterable and using unpacking to assign each value from the iterable to an equivalent number of variables.

Comment: @e-satis: I know that, but for documentation purposes it would be useful to detect the types of the values in the iterable rather than just generate a generic "returns a sequence". Regardless, I doubt that ST could even figure that out except perhaps in the simplest cases.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe string replacements are helpful for you. Here is a short snippet from Idle to demonstrate the syntax.

```
>>> a = 123
>>> b = "abc"
>>> "%(a)s, %(b)s" % locals()
'123, abc'
>>> "%d, %s" % (a,b)
'123, abc'
```

to get the type:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> print type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(a).__name__
'int'
```

`x.__name__` is a private attribute however it is "accessible"